# Use Wildcard SSL in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl-certificate, nopcommerce

I have a *Wildcard SSL certificate*. I want to use it in **nopcommerce** version 2.5. I can see a feature in admin section it say use SSL and then it ask for **Shared SSL URL:** and **Non-secured URL:**. Does this **Shared SSL** means same as **Wildcard SSL**. Please anyone can help me How to use Wildcard SSL in nopcommerce.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it's a URL that has an SSL certificate on it. Doesn't necessarily mean a wildcard although it could be a wildcard, SAN, or a standard single domain certificate.